# In which method is background view dequeued for UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I use `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`. All the sections have rounded background. The background is just added to all the sections

```
    let background = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind: "background")
    section.decorationItems = [background]
```

and later registered

```
    layout.register(RoundedView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: "background")
```

The question is: how to change the color for the background view? Is there a function where the view is dequeued? I've already tried

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    preconditionFailure("")
}
```

But it's not invoked

All related code:
Pretty stupid background view

```
final class RoundedView: UICollectionReusableView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        config()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        config()
    }

    private func config() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = Constant.Dimens.cornerRadius
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Making the layout

```
@available(iOS 13, *)
private static func makeLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(100))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(200))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)

    let background = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind: "background")
    section.decorationItems = [background]

    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
    layout.register(RoundedView.self, forDecorationViewOfKind: "background")
    return layout
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to get background view invoked, you can not use

```
let background = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(elementKind: "background")
section.decorationItems = [background]
```

I used a bit different way to get them called and made them **boundarySupplementaryItems**

```
///Background
let sectionBackgroundSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
            heightDimension: groupSize.heightDimension)
let sectionBackgroundAnchor = NSCollectionLayoutAnchor(edges: [.all])
let sectionBackground = NSCollectionLayoutBoundarySupplementaryItem(
            layoutSize: sectionBackgroundSize,
            elementKind: ReusableViewBackgroundSupplimentaryView.elementKindSectionBackground, /// "background"
            containerAnchor: sectionBackgroundAnchor)
section.boundarySupplementaryItems = [sectionBackground]
```

register the view(**RoundedView** in your case) in collectionview like header/footer view.

```
collectionView.register(ReusableViewBackgroundSupplimentaryView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: ReusableViewBackgroundSupplimentaryView.elementKindSectionBackground, withReuseIdentifier: ReusableViewBackgroundSupplimentaryView.reuseIdentifier)
```

Now you'll get your callback either in

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
/// Match your stupid identifier "background"
/// ReusableViewBackgroundSupplimentaryView.elementKindSectionBackground
}
```

or modern diffable dataSource

```
dataSource?.supplementaryViewProvider = { (
            collectionView: UICollectionView,
            kind: String,
            indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView? in
   /// Match your stupid identifier "background"
    /// ReusableViewBackgroundSupplimentaryView.elementKindSectionBackground
    /// return collectionView.dequeueSuplementaryView(...)
    }
```

Now enjoy!

Comment: The background views height doesn't fit automatically for me. You might be able to get it to work if you know the height beforehand.

Comment: This worked for me with an absolute size. If you're section has a header too, you'll need to set the supp items like this: boundarySupplementaryItems = [sectionBackground, header]. Otherwise, the background will cover the header.